Probability of winning in a 2 players coin tossing game

You will play a coin game against an opponent. A biased coin will be continually flipped where there is a $2/3$ chance of Heads and a $1/3$ chance of Tails. If Heads is flipped then you receive $\$1$ from your opponent. If Tails is flipped then you pay $\$1$ to your opponent. You start with $\$10$ and your opponent starts with $\$20$. You keep playing until one of you is bankrupt (= has $\$0$ left); they will be declared the loser, the other will be declared the winner. What is the probability, that you win?

I know intuitively I have a higher chance of winning (say >50%). My thought process was to solve this question by modeling a series of recurrence equations. But, this will lead to an exhaustive list of equations I must solve. I was asked this question on an online test where the time limit for this question was 1 minute. What shortcuts or tricks I can use to solve this in that short amount of time? Because solving for every single recurrence equation was just not feasible. And, I cannot just plug these values into the traditional Gambler's Ruin formula because the probabilities are not equal. Thank you!

You can proceed as follows : given a probability $p$ of winning a round (and $1-p$ of losing), assuming you start with $a$\$ and your opponent with $b$\$, denote by $P_a$ the probability of winning the entire game from this initial configuration. Note that $a+b = N$ is fixed throughout the game.
Try then to show a relation of the form :
$$ P_a = p P_{a+1} + (1-p) P_{a-1} $$
for any $a$.
This can be rewritten as a second order recurrence relation giving $P_{a+1}$ as a function of $P_a$ and $P_{a-1}$. Therefore, it has a unique solution, given $P_0 = 0$ and $P_N = 1$.
You should eventually find
$$ P_a = \frac{1 - \left( \frac{1-p}{p} \right)^a}{1 - \left( \frac{1-p}{p} \right)^N} $$
as long as $p \neq \frac{1}{2}$ (because in this specific case the characteristic polynomial of your recurrence relation has $1$ as a double root, while the roots are distinct for any other case).

I plugged in the values to that formula, where $ p = \frac{2}{3}$, $a = 10$, and $N = 10+20 = 30$, and got an answer close to 0.999, is this correct?

Very probably : $(1-p)/p = 1/2$ in this case, and so both the numerator and denominator of $P_a$ are close to $1$ given the "large" values of $a, N$.
